# React не рендирит изменения компонента при изменении props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate

задача такая -> с сервера подтягиваются данные автомобиля отображаются в таблице, при нажатии кнопки появляется модальное окно и автозаполняется форма. Данные автомобилей загружаются и хранятся в useState в виде обьекта.

```
const [shopCars, setShopCars] = useState(false);
if (data['success']){
   if (data.cars.length > 0)
      setShopCars(data.cars)
```

Далее этот массив передается компоненту в качестве пропса

```
<AdminTableCarsPage setShopCars={setShopCars} shopData={shopData} shopCars={shopCars} mainData={props.mainData} />
```

В этом компоненте автомобили отображаются в таблице. Также в данном компоненте имеется состояние

```
const [focusCarID, setFocusCarID] = useState(0);
```

и еще один компонент (модальное окно) в котором при изменении состояния focusCarID должна авто-заполняться форма

При нажатии на кнопку изменить данные состояние обновляется

```
<div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
   <Link className="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#EditCarShop" onClick={(event) => setFocusCarID(i)}>Изменить данные</Link>
</div>
```

после того как состояние обновилась оно передается компоненту № 2 (модальной форме) вместе с массивом всех автомобилей

```
<AdminModalEditCar focusCarID={focusCarID} setShopCars={props.setShopCars} shopCars={props.shopCars} sp_cars={props.mainData.sp_cars} id_shop={props.shopData.id} />
```

в компоненте № 2 (модальном окне) получаю данные автомобиля следующим способом

```
props.shopCars[props.focusCarID]
```

Проблема в следующем ->

1. Компонент модального окна получает все пропсы но не обновляет форму при изменении props.focusCarID из за этого форма не автозаполняется. Плюс focusCarID обновляется с задержкой в один шаг, например, я выбираю первый автомобиль его данные модальное окно не видит, потом я выбираю второй автомобиль модальное окно видит данные первого, потом я выбираю третий автомобиль модальное окно видит данные второго и тд. Если ктото понял что не так помогите пожалуйста.

---

Код компонента где отрисовывается таблица с данными

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import AdminModalEditCar from "./AdminModalEditCar";

const AdminTableCarsPage = (props) => {

const [focusCarID, setFocusCarID] = useState(false);

return (
    <div>
        <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Марка</th>
                <th scope="col">Модель</th>
                <th scope="col">Дата выпуска</th>
                <th scope="col">Vin номер</th>
                <th scope="col">Гос. номер</th>
                <th scope="col">Состояния</th>
                <th scope="col">Цена авто</th>
                <th scope="col">Цена всех запчастей</th>
                <th scope="col">Дата покупки</th>
                <th scope="col">Действия</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {
                Object.keys(props.shopCars).map((index, i) => {
                    return <tr key={i+1}>
                        <th scope="row">{i+1}</th>
                        <td>{props.shopCars[index].marka['name']}</td>
                        <td>{props.shopCars[index].model}</td>
                        <td>{props.shopCars[index].date_create}</td>
                        <td>{props.shopCars[index].vinnomer}</td>
                        <td>{props.shopCars[index].gosnomer}</td>
                        <td>{props.shopCars[index].status}</td>
                        <td>{props.shopCars[index].price} руб.</td>
                        <td>{props.shopCars[index].summ_all_parts} руб.</td>
                        <td>{props.shopCars[index].date_add}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div className="dropdown">
                                <button className="btn btn-дшпре dropdown-toggle" type="button"
                                        id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Действия
                                </button>
                                <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                    <Link className="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#EditCarShop" onClick={(event) => setFocusCarID(props.shopCars[index].id)}>Изменить данные</Link>
                                    <Link className="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target={"#viewPartsCar_" + i}>Запчасти</Link>
                                    <Link className="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target={"#deleteCarShop_" + i}>Удалить</Link>
                                    <Link className="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#DeleteUserShop">Финансы</Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                })
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <AdminModalEditCar setShopCars={props.setShopCars} editCarData={{}} focusCarID={focusCarID} sp_cars={props.mainData.sp_cars} id_shop={props.shopData.id} />

        {/*<AdminModalCarPart sp_shops={props.mainData.sp_shops} sp_cars={props.mainData.sp_cars} sp_parts={props.mainData.sp_parts} carData={props.shopCars[index]}id_shop={props.shopData.id} />*/}
        {/*<AdminModalDeleteCarShop setShopCars={props.setShopCars} id_shop={props.shopData.id} id_car={props.shopCars[index].id} />*/}

        </div>
   );
};

export default AdminTableCarsPage;
```

Код компонента модального окна в котором форма изменения данных

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import Modal from "../../../components/Modal/Modal";
import Select from "react-select"
import {useState} from "react";
import ImgAds from "../../../components/ImgFormPreview/ImgAds";
import sendForm from "../../../utility/SendForm";
import apiRequest from "../../../utility/ApiRequest";
import $ from 'jquery';
import {objectSize} from "../../../utility/Utility";
import LoadingIcon from "../../../components/LoadingIcon/LoadingIcon";

let indexLastImage = 0;

const AdminModalEditCar = (props) => {

const [displayImgAds, setdisplayImgAds] = useState([]);
const [sendAddNewCar, setSendAddNewCar] = useState(false);

const [dateshop, setDateShop] = useState("");
const [dateCreateCar, setDateCreateCar] = useState("");
const [adsAvtoMarka, setAdsAvtoMarka] = useState("");
const [issetImages, setIssetImages] = useState({});
const [defaultMarkaAvto, setDefaultMarkaAvto] = useState("");

const [editCarData, setEditCarData] = useState({});
const [loadDataCar, setloadDataCar] = useState(false);

useEffect(()=> {
    console.log(props.focusCarID);
    if (props.focusCarID){
        setloadDataCar(false);
        setEditCarData({});

        apiRequest("getDataCar?", "id_shop=" + props.id_shop + "&id_car=" + props.focusCarID).then((data) => {
           if(data['success']){
               setloadDataCar(true);
               if (data['dataCar'])
                setEditCarData(data['dataCar']);
           } else console.log(data['error']);
        });


        if (objectSize(editCarData)) {
            setDateShop(editCarData.date_add);
            setDateCreateCar(editCarData.date_create);
            setAdsAvtoMarka(editCarData.marka['id']);
            setIssetImages(editCarData.images);
            setDefaultMarkaAvto(editCarData.marka['id']);
            $('#editCarSelect option[value="' + editCarData.status + '"]').prop('selected', true);
        }
    }
}, [props.focusCarID]);

const addImgAds = (event) => {
    let arrImg = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
        indexLastImage++;
        event.target.files[i]['rotate'] = 0;
        arrImg.push({"file": event.target.files[i], "url" : URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]), "index": indexLastImage});
    }
    setdisplayImgAds([...displayImgAds, ...arrImg]);
    event.target.value = null;
}

const deleteImgAds = (idImg) => {
    setdisplayImgAds(displayImgAds.filter(obj => {
        return obj['index'] !== idImg;
    }));
}

const deleteImageServer = (id_img, id_cars, id_shop) => {
    apiRequest("deleteCarImg?", "id_shop=" + id_shop + "&id_cars=" + id_cars + "&id_img=" + id_img).then((data) => {
       if (data['success']){
           setIssetImages(issetImages.filter(i => i.indexOf(id_img) < 0));
       } else
           alert(data['error']);
    });
}

const addNewCar = (event) => {

    event.preventDefault();

    if (!sendAddNewCar){
        let files = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < displayImgAds.length; i++)
            files.push(displayImgAds[i]['file']);

        setSendAddNewCar(true);

        sendForm(event, (data) => {
            if (data['success']){
                if (data['cars'])
                    props.setShopCars(data['cars']);
            }
            setSendAddNewCar(false);
        }, true, false, true, files);
    }
}

return (
    <Modal size="modal-xl" title="Изменение данных автомобиля" id="EditCarShop">
        {
            (loadDataCar)
                ? (objectSize(editCarData) === 0)
                    ? <div className="alert alert-danger">Данные автомобиля не найдены.</div>
                    : <form onSubmit={(event) => addNewCar(event)} action="editCarShop" id={"formEditCarShop_" + props.id} method="POST"
                        className="needs-validation" noValidate>

                    <div className="form-group row">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPassword" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Марка</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <Select
                                options={props.sp_cars}
                                placeholder="Марка автомобиля"
                                isSearchable={true}
                                onChange={(event) => setAdsAvtoMarka(event.value)}
                                defaultValue = {
                                    props.sp_cars.filter(option =>
                                        option.value === parseInt(defaultMarkaAvto))
                                }
                            />
                            <input name="marka" type="text" defaultValue={adsAvtoMarka} className="d-none" required />
                            <div className="valid-feedback">
                                <i className="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up-fill"></i> Заполнено
                            </div>
                            <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                Поле обязательно к заполнению
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" className="d-none" defaultValue={props.id_shop} name="id_shop" />
                    <input type="text" className="d-none" defaultValue={
                        (objectSize(props.editCarData))
                            ? props.editCarData.id
                            : false
                    } name="id_car" />
                    <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPassword" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Модель</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="model" defaultValue={
                                (objectSize(props.editCarData))
                                    ? props.editCarData.model
                                    : false
                            } placeholder="Camry" required />
                            <div className="valid-feedback">
                                <i className="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up-fill"></i> Заполнено
                            </div>
                            <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                Поле обязательно к заполнению
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPassword" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">VIN номер</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="vinnomer" placeholder="Z94CB41AACR123456" defaultValue={
                                (objectSize(props.editCarData))
                                    ? props.editCarData.vinnomer
                                    : false
                            } required />
                            <div className="valid-feedback">
                                <i className="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up-fill"></i> Заполнено
                            </div>
                            <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                Поле обязательно к заполнению
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPassword" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Гос. номер</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="gosnomer" placeholder="А637АА93" defaultValue={
                                (objectSize(props.editCarData))
                                    ? props.editCarData.gosnomer
                                    : false
                            } required />
                            <div className="valid-feedback">
                                <i className="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up-fill"></i> Заполнено
                            </div>
                            <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                Поле обязательно к заполнению
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPassword" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Дата выпуска</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-auto">
                            <input type="date" className="form-control" placeholder="" defaultValue={
                                (objectSize(props.editCarData))
                                    ? props.editCarData.date_create
                                    : false
                            } required onChange={(event) => setDateCreateCar(event.target.value)} />
                            <input type="text" className="form-control d-none" name="date_create" defaultValue={dateCreateCar} placeholder="" />
                            <div className="valid-feedback">
                                <i className="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up-fill"></i> Заполнено
                            </div>
                            <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                Поле обязательно к заполнению
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPassword" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Состояние</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <select id="editCarSelect" className="form-select" name="state" required>
                                <option value="">Выберите из списка</option>
                                <option value="Битая">Битая</option>
                                <option value="Не битая">Не битая</option>
                            </select>
                            <div className="valid-feedback">
                                <i className="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up-fill"></i> Заполнено
                            </div>
                            <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                Поле обязательно к заполнению
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPassword" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Цена</label>
                        <div className="col-auto">
                            <div className="input-group mb-2">
                                <input type="number" className="form-control" name="price"
                                       placeholder="0" defaultValue={
                                    (objectSize(props.editCarData))
                                        ? props.editCarData.price_sys
                                        : false
                                } required />
                                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div className="input-group-text">руб.</div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="valid-feedback">
                                    <i className="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up-fill"></i> Заполнено
                                </div>
                                <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                    Поле обязательно к заполнению
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPassword" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Дата покупки</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-auto">
                            <input type="date" className="form-control" defaultValue={dateshop} required onChange={(event) => setDateShop(event.target.value)} />
                            <input type="text" className="form-control d-none" name="date" defaultValue={dateshop} placeholder="" />
                            <div className="valid-feedback">
                                <i className="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up-fill"></i> Заполнено
                            </div>
                            <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                Поле обязательно к заполнению
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPassword" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Комментарии к покупке</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                <textarea rows="5" name="comment" className="form-control" defaultValue={
                    (objectSize(props.editCarData))
                        ? props.editCarData.description
                        : false
                }>

                </textarea>
                            <div className="valid-feedback">
                                <i className="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up-fill"></i> Заполнено
                            </div>
                            <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                Поле обязательно к заполнению
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr />

                    <div className="mt-3 w-100">
                        <div className="d-flex flex-row d-inline flex-wrap" id="AdsImgContainer">
                            {
                                (objectSize(props.editCarData))
                                    ? (Object.keys(issetImages).length)
                                        ? Object.keys(issetImages).map((image, key) => {
                                            return (
                                                <ImgAds src={props.editCarData.images[image]} id_shop={props.id_shop} id_cars={props.editCarData.id} id_img={image.split("/")[props.editCarData.images[image].split("/").length - 1]} key={key} deleteImageServer={deleteImageServer} deleteImgServer={true} />
                                            )
                                        })
                                        : false
                                    : false
                            }
                            {
                                (displayImgAds.length)
                                    ? displayImgAds.map((image, key) => {
                                        return (
                                            <ImgAds src={image['url']} id_img={image.index} deleteImage={deleteImgAds} key={key} />
                                        )
                                    })
                                    : false
                            }
                        </div>
                        <label className="btn btn-default d-inline">
                            <div style={styles.imagebutton}>
                                <i className="bi bi-camera"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="file" multiple="multiple" onChange={(event) => addImgAds(event)} hidden />
                        </label>
                    </div>


                    <div className="alert alert-danger d-none mt-3">

                    </div>
                    <div className="alert alert-success mt-3 d-none">

                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Добавить автомобиль" className="btn btn-success mt-3"/>
                </form>
                : (loadDataCar)
                    ? false
                    : <LoadingIcon />
        }

        </Modal>
    );
};

const styles = {
    imagebutton: {
        paddingLeft: 30,
        paddingRight: 30,
        paddingTop: 20,
        paddingBottom: 20,
        fontSize: 40,
        color: "#abd6fc",
        borderColor: "#abd6fc",
        borderStyle: "solid",
        borderWidth: 1,
    }
}

export default AdminModalEditCar;
```

Comment: Нужны подробности. Как эти компоненты взаимодействую, что за модалка такая, как вызывается и как в нее передаются данные

Comment: setFocusCarID асинхронный. потому ты получаешь предыдущее значение в props

Comment: В модальном окне данные получаются через props, создаются состоянии для каждого элемента данных массива и уже эти состоянии вставляются в input-ы формы.

Comment: А как получать текущие значения useState ?

Comment: Покажите, как эти все компоненты связаны между собой. Без этой информации сложно что либо сказать однозначно. Тонно можно посоветовать: надо мыслить так, что вы даете команду обновить состояние, а само оно изменится когда то в будущем и ваш код должен на это реагировать.

Comment: Подозреваю, что проблема в useEffect. Вы там делаете `setEditCarData(data['dataCar']);` и чуть ниже проверяете `objectSize(editCarData)` и сетите значения `setDateShop(editCarData.date_add);`, однако забываете, что установка значений, это асинхронная операция. При первом вызвове у вас `editCarData === {}`. Уже чуть позже, данные приедут в нужную переменную(отсюда и пустота). При втором вызове аналогично, но в `editCarData` лежат еще данные от первого вызова.

Comment: И ваш код на jQuery должен быть убран из кода React и переписан под механизмы реакта.

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что проблема в useEffect.

Вы там делаете `setEditCarData(data['dataCar']);` и чуть ниже проверяете `objectSize(editCarData)` (первый сеттер состояния еще не отработал) и сетите значения `setDateShop(editCarData.date_add);`, однако забываете, что установка значений, это асинхронная операция.

При первом вызвове у вас `editCarData === {}`. Уже чуть позже, данные приедут в нужную переменную(отсюда и пустота).

При втором вызове аналогично, но в `editCarData` лежат еще данные от предыдущего вызова

Вот так, скорее всего, должен выглядеть ваш useEffect

```
useEffect(()=> {
  if (props.focusCarID){
    setloadDataCar(false);
    setEditCarData({});

    apiRequest("getDataCar?", "id_shop=" + props.id_shop + "&id_car=" + props.focusCarID)
      .then((data) => {
      if(data['success']){
        setloadDataCar(true);
        if (objectSize(data['dataCar'])) {
          setEditCarData(data['dataCar']);
          setDateShop(data['dataCar'].date_add);
          setDateCreateCar(data['dataCar'].date_create);
          setAdsAvtoMarka(data['dataCar'].marka['id']);
          setIssetImages(data['dataCar'].images);
          setDefaultMarkaAvto(data['dataCar'].marka['id']);
          $('#editCarSelect option[value="' + data['dataCar'].status + '"]').prop('selected', true);
        }

      } else console.log(data['error']);
    });
    
  }
}, [props.focusCarID]);
```

код jQuery не убирал - это отдельная история, которая к данному вопросу не относится.